# Is there any point to using Any() linq expression for optimisation purposes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, optimization

I have a MVC application which returns 2 types of Json responses from 2 controller methods; AnyRemindersExist() and GetAllUserReminders(). The first returns a boolean, 2nd returns an array, both wrapped as Json.

I have a JavaScript timer checking for calendar reminders against a user. It makes the first call (AnyRemindersExist) to check whether reminders exist and whether the client should then make the 2nd call.

For example, if the result of the Json response is false from the Any() query, it doesn't then make the 2nd controller action which makes a LINQ select call. If there are reminders that exist, it then goes further and then requests them (making use of the LINQ SELECT).

Imagine a system ramped up where 100-1000s users use the system and on the client, every 30-60 seconds a request comes in to load in the reminders.  Does this Any() call help in anyway in reducing load on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it depends on how the underlying queries are translated.  If the `any` call is translated into an indexed lookup when the `select` (perhaps due to a join to get related data) must do some sort of table scan, then it will save some work in the case when there are no reminders to be found.  It will cause a little extra work when there are reminders.  It might be useful if the majority of the calls don't result in any results.

In the general case, though, I would just select the data and only try to optimize IF that turns out to not be fast enough.  The conditions under which it will actually save effort on the server are pretty narrow and might only apply if you hand-craft the SQL rather than depend on your ORM.

Answer (score 2):

If you're *always* going to get the actual values afterwards, then no - it would make more sense to have fewer requests, and just always give the full results. I very much doubt that returning no results is slower than returning an indication that there are no results.

EDIT: tvanfosson's latest comment (at the time of this writing) is worth promoting:

> You can really only tell by measuring and I'd only resort to it IFF the performance of the select only option didn't meet the requirements.

That's the most important thing about performance: the value of a guess is much less than the value of test data.

Comment: I think you're right in the general case, but I could see where a "are there any reminders for this person" call then a "get the reminders between now and an hour from now" might be translated in such a way as to do an index seek in the first case and a table scan  in the second depending on the indexes on the table and the exact query formulated. It looks like a case of premature (and maybe inverse) optimization.

Comment: @tvanfosson: But that's a different case - it would be more appropriate to compare "are there any reminders between now and an hour from now" and "get the reminders between now and an hour from now" - surely both could use indexes in that case... if you change the filter part of the query then it's a different matter.

Comment: without knowing the exact details of the implementation it's hard to tell.  My example was probably poorly chosen, but what if there's a `Deleted` column and you want to find only those reminders that haven't been deleted.  Let's also say that you put an index on the deleted column.  If `AnyRemindersExists` checks for undeleted reminders, then it would likely use this index and do an index scan.  `GetAllUserReminders` probably only cares about reminders in the future and does a date based filtering that may result in the optimizer choosing to ignore the index and do a table scan.

Comment: @tvanfosson: That sounds like the query optimizer is doing the wrong thing in that case - if we're going to assume the query optimizer can screw up, then doesn't that mean all bets are off?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that the optimizer is wrong, but rather that the other query may be more complex and result in a different strategy that better suits that query.  Perhaps, the first one can do a simple exists where the second needs to join across other tables to get some preferences in how the alert is displayed or whether its applicable to this client, etc.  It may not be as simple as index seek vs. table scan but I'm hesitant to say that there are no circumstances in which it would help due to differences in the way the query is handled.

Answer (score 1):

`Any` only checks to see if there is at least one item in the Collection that is being returned. Versus using something like `Count > 0` which counts the total amount of items in the collection then yes this is more optimal.

If your `AnyRemindersExist` method is operating on a similar principle then not calling a second call to the server would reduce your load.

Answer (score 0):

So you are asking if not doing work the application doesn't need to do would reduce the workload on the server?

Of course.  How would this answer every be "yes, doing extra work for no reason won't effect the server load".

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It ultimately depends on how much faster the `Any` check is compared to getting the results and how often it will be false.</strike>

- If the `Any` call takes near as long as the `select` then it pretty
  much never makes sense.
- If the `Any` call is much faster than the `select` but 90% of the
  time it's **true**, then it probably isn't worth it (best case you
  get 10% improvement, worst case it's actually more work).
- If the `Any` call is much faster than the `select` and 90% of the
  time it's **false**, then it probably makes sense to check if there
  are any before actually getting results.

So the answer is it depends on your specific scenario.  Ultimately you're going to need to measure both the relative performance (on different typical loads, maybe some queries are more intensive than others) as well as the frequency that there are no results to return.

**Actually it should almost never make sense to check `Any` in this case.**

- If `Any` returns `false` then you don't need to grab the results.
  However this means it would have returned no results anyway, so
  unless your `Any` check is significantly faster than a `select`
  returning 0 results, there's no added benefit here.
- On the other hand, if `Any` returns true, then you'll need to get the
  results anyway, so in this case `Any` is purely additional work done.